# How can I average two vectors only if their individual difference is less than 5 in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| time_stamp | sensor_index | humidity | temperature | pm2.5_a | pm2.5_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 15:00:00 | 51377 | 37.434 | 102.834 | 18.209 | 17.264 |
| 2022-07-11 22:00:00 | 51377 | 31.267 | 102.367 | 7.982 | 8.971 |
| 2022-07-11 00:00:00 | 51377 | 43.533 | 91.5 | 10.518 | 12.260 |
| 2022-07-11 14:00:00 | 51377 | 51.433 | 95.7 | 14.168 | 20.168 |

I'm trying to apply a correction factor that averages pm2.5_a and pm2.5_b if there difference is less than ±5.

The formula is `if(pm2.5_a-pm2.5_b is <±5 then 0.52*(average of pm2.5_a & pm2.5_b) - 0.085*humidity + 5.71, else nothing)`

My desired output would look like this:

| time_stamp | sensor_index | humidity | temperature | pm2.5_a | pm2.5_b | pm_cor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 15:00:00 | 51377 | 37.434 | 102.834 | 18.209 | 17.264 | 11.75 |
| 2022-07-11 22:00:00 | 51377 | 31.267 | 102.367 | 7.982 | 8.971 | 7.46 |
| 2022-07-11 00:00:00 | 51377 | 43.533 | 91.5 | 10.518 | 12.260 | 7.93 |
| 2022-07-11 14:00:00 | 51377 | 51.433 | 95.7 | 14.168 | 20.168 |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `case_when` or `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
 mutate(pm_cor = case_when(abs(pm2.5_a-pm2.5_b ) < 5 ~
    0.52 * rowMeans(cbind( pm2.5_a,pm2.5_b ), na.rm = TRUE) - 
          0.085*humidity + 5.71))
```

-output

```
df1
          time_stamp sensor_index humidity temperature pm2.5_a pm2.5_b    pm_cor
1 2022-07-15 15:00:00        51377   37.434     102.834  18.209  17.264 11.751090
2 2022-07-11 22:00:00        51377   31.267     102.367   7.982   8.971  7.460085
3 2022-07-11 00:00:00        51377   43.533      91.500  10.518  12.260  7.931975
4 2022-07-11 14:00:00        51377   51.433      95.700  14.168  20.168        NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(time_stamp = c("2022-07-15 15:00:00", "2022-07-11 22:00:00", 
"2022-07-11 00:00:00", "2022-07-11 14:00:00"), sensor_index = c(51377L, 
51377L, 51377L, 51377L), humidity = c(37.434, 31.267, 43.533, 
51.433), temperature = c(102.834, 102.367, 91.5, 95.7), pm2.5_a = c(18.209, 
7.982, 10.518, 14.168), pm2.5_b = c(17.264, 8.971, 12.26, 20.168
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when I use this: "Caused by error in `0.085 * humidity`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
  100: <Anonymous>" I do have some NULL values in my humidity data, could that be throwing it?

Comment: @Kyle Please check the `str(yourdata)`.  Maybe some columns are not numeric.  If that is the case, convert the column i.e. `yourdata$humidity <- as.numeric(yourdata$humidity)` before applying this

Comment: @Kyle Please use `dput` to show a small reproduccible example so that others can test it correctly i.e. `dput(head(yourdata))`

Comment: as.numeric did the trick, thank you so much for your help!